# Transpose Filtered Column As String to Cell

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, transpose

I have a table which looks like this:
[image]

I wrote code which gives output like this:
[image]

The goal is a results table which does the following:

- Count number of times "old" status appears
- Count numer of times "new" status appears
- Get all the (unique) old groups in one cell
- Get all the (unique) new groups in one cell

The following code worked on one computer but not on another (both Windows, 64bit):

```vb
Sub TableSummary()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim new_tbl As ListObject, old_tbl As ListObject
    Dim new_array As Variant, old_array As Variant
    
    '2. Disable Screen Updating - stop screen flickering and Disable Events to avoid inturupted dialogs / popups
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    '4. Add a new summary table to summary worksheet
    With ActiveWorkbook
        sht.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, sht.UsedRange, , xlYes).Name = "Summary"
        sht.ListObjects("Summary").TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium5"
    End With

    i = 1
    For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sht.Name = "Summary" Then
            'Define Column Headers of Summary
            sht.Cells(1, 4).Resize(1, 4).Value = Array("Nbr of old", "Nbr of new", "Groups old", "Groups new")
        
            i = i + 1
            
            For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
                ' Blue table
                If tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2" Then
                    sht.Range("D" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tbl.Range, "old")
                    sht.Range("E" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(tbl.Range, "new")
        
                    Set new_tbl = sht.ListObjects("Summary")
                    Set new_tbl = sht.ListObjects("Summary").Range().AutoFilter(Field:=2, Criteria1:="old")
                    new_array = Application.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Unique(sht.ListObjects("Summary").ListColumns("Group").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))) 'This doesn't work on my other machine
                    sht.Range("F" & i).Value = Join(new_array, ", ") 'works!
                    'Debug.Print Join(new_array, ", ")
        
                    sht.ListObjects("Summary").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                    Set new_tbl = sht.ListObjects("Summary")
                    Set new_tbl = sht.ListObjects("Summary").Range().AutoFilter(Field:=2, Criteria1:="new")
                    new_array = Application.Transpose(WorksheetFunction.Unique(sht.ListObjects("Summary").ListColumns("Group").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))) 'This doesn't work on my other machine
                    sht.Range("G" & i).Value = Join(new_array, ", ") 'works!
                    Debug.Print Join(new_array, ", ")
        
                    sht.ListObjects("Summary").AutoFilter.ShowAllData
                    
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

`Application.Transpose` does not work on my second machine.

Comment: Was there an error message? How specifically did `Application.Transpose` fail?

Comment: There was no error message, but the array is always empty.

Comment: There's a lot going on in those `Transpose` lines, so maybe split them up a bit so you can figure out where the issue is.

Comment: You have a loop with `For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects`, but inside that loop you only refer to `tbl` in the `CountIf` lines - otherwise it's always `sht.ListObjects(1)` you work with. Is there only ever one listobject per sheet?  Where is `sht` assigned?  Also some confusion there with `pending_array` vs. `new_array`

Comment: The bigger issue though is you can't call `Transpose()` on a non-contiguous range, so unless your data is sorted on Col2, your approach will error out.

Comment: @TimWilliams I just realized I initially pasted the false code. It's edited now. There can be multiple listobjects per sheet, but there's only one blue one (`TableStyleMedium5`) per sheet. They all have different colors. I actually loop through all of the workbook's sheets, but here I only used a "Summary" sheet for illustrative purposes. How can it be that this works on one machine and on another one not?

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.Unique()` only works on a single-area (contiguous) range.  And `sht` is still not assigned in your updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different approach using a function to create the list of unique values:

```vb
Sub TableSummary()
    Const NEW_OLD_COL As Long = 2
    Const GROUP_COL As String = "Group"
    Const VAL_OLD As String = "old"
    Const VAL_NEW As String = "new"
    
    Dim sht As Worksheet, DstSht As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim new_tbl As ListObject, old_tbl As ListObject
    Dim new_array As Variant, old_array As Variant
    
    Set sht = ActiveSheet 'or whatever...
    Set DstSht = sht
    i = 2
    
    For Each tbl In sht.ListObjects
        ' Blue table
        If tbl.TableStyle = "TableStyleMedium2" Then
            
            With tbl.ListColumns(NEW_OLD_COL)
                DstSht.Range("G" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.DataBodyRange, VAL_OLD)
                DstSht.Range("H" & i).Value = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.DataBodyRange, VAL_NEW)
            End With
            
            tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=NEW_OLD_COL, Criteria1:="new"
            DstSht.Range("I" & i).Value = VisibleUniques(tbl, GROUP_COL)
            tbl.Range.AutoFilter
    
            tbl.Range.AutoFilter Field:=NEW_OLD_COL, Criteria1:="old"
            DstSht.Range("J" & i).Value = VisibleUniques(tbl, GROUP_COL)
            tbl.Range.AutoFilter
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'Return a comma-separated list of all unique values in visible cells in 
'   column `ColName` of listobject `tbl`
Function VisibleUniques(tbl As ListObject, ColName As String) As String
    Dim rngVis As Range, dict As Object, c As Range
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no visible cells
    Set rngVis = tbl.ListColumns(ColName).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0      'stop ignoring errors
    If rngVis Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rngVis.Cells
        dict(CStr(c.Value)) = True
    Next c
    VisibleUniques = Join(dict.keys, ", ")
End Function
```